# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un campo de modelo según una condición? Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

### Formulario

```
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Perfil
    fields = ['tel','tel_fijo','entrg_pais','entrg_dep','entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion',
                'entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep','rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp',
                'num_cc','avatar','propietario_cc','banco','tipo_cc','tipo_ident','cedula_o_nit','descp_armario',
                'acepta_politicas']
```

Quiero deshabilitar el campo `acepta_politicas` cuando la haya marcado la primera vez como True y que no pueda modificar el valor.

Comment: Hola amigo eso lo puedes hacer en el template cunado se renderiza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso lo puedes lograr desde el método `__init__` de tu clase de formulario, de esta forma:

```
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = [
            'tel', 'tel_fijo', 'entrg_pais', 'entrg_dep',
            'entrg_ciudad', 'entrg_direccion', 'entrg_cp',
            'rmt_pais', 'rmt_dep', 'rmt_direccion', 'rmt_ciudad',
            'rmt_cp', 'num_cc', 'avatar', 'propietario_cc', 'banco',
            'tipo_cc', 'tipo_ident', 'cedula_o_nit', 'descp_armario',
            'acepta_politicas'
        ]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk and self.instance.acepta_politicas:
            self.fields['acepta_politicas'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled': true})
```

Comment: Gracias, no sabia como sacar la información del objeto